Kivy - Images appear pixelated
I am using a Rectangle() Instruction added to a Canvas() to display a rather large .png which results in the image looking quite pixelated.
Here is the original and the rendered version in kivy.
Am i missing something obvious that would make the scaling "this bad"?



Maybe add the actual code and include the actual source image you used. Perhaps directly using Texture may help you

It doesn't matter the image, always looks like the above.
InstructionGroup().add(Rectangle(source=self.image, pos=pos, size=size)) results in the image being distorted (see the 2nd one).
I will look into Texture, thanks.

The Rectangle does not do any antialiasing. Do you see the same effect if you display the image using an Image widget?

Using an Image Widget, it looks as it should.
The reason i am using a ´Rectangle´ is the fact that i wasn't able to use an Image as an Instruction.
Is there a way to add an Effect to the Instruction, just as an Image widget would have?
